# Boost converter Controlling problem when transfer from light load to heavy load

Tags: boost, dcm-ccm

I built a boost converter to boost voltage from 200V dc to 400V dc. Power rating is 5kw,
I added a PID to regulate the voltage. The problem is, when going from light load to heavy load, output voltage causes overshoot. After going to heavy load, further load addition has no problems.
For ex, lets say the converter is operating at 30w. Then if I added a 500w load, output overshoot happens. After that, even if i added a 2kw load, no problem occurs. If i reduced the PID gains to compensate this issue, then output voltage regulation at the 30w to 500w transfer become too slow that it takes about 1-2 seconds to come to the set point and the output voltage is dipped to input voltage at the start.

Duty cycle equation for CCM given by, D= 1-(Vin/Vout).
PID output value is tally with this equation when there is heavy load. However at light load, there is a large difference between the PID output and this "D" value.
If i hard coded this Duty cycle, output voltage go to a higher value  than the calculated value.
Once a heavy load, say 500w added to this, then voltage come back to the calculated value.

I think this is happening due to the boost converter going to continuous conduction mode from discontinuous conduction mode. Am i right?
Is there any special way to deal with DCM?.
How handle this DCM to CCM transfer properly?.

Duty cycle difference between light load and large load is about 0.3. This larger duty cycle jump creates overshoot. If i slowed down the PID to compensate this, it become too much slow.

Thank you
Damith

Comment: Have you a "predictive" circuit that can overcome this problem? Measuring the power load and fixing then the duty cycle.

Comment: Sounds like you need to recompensate your loop.

Comment: Problem is compensation is not suitable when the device parameters changed from DCM to CCM.
as i said in the question, if the compensator is tubed to heavy load, it doesn't compensate at light load, and vice versa